# Try - Catch not responding properly when JSON has a backslash

Tags: node.js

I have a router.post as follows

```
router.post('/newlead', async (payload, res, next) => {
...
...
...
});
```

Payload is coming on the body, as a JSON object, for example

```
{
    "name": "Danielle",
    "age": 26
}
```

When I send a body like this:

```
{
    "name": "\Danielle",
    "age": 26
}
```

I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position X.
```

I tried by JSON.parse(payload.body) within a try{}catch{} and I still get the error, its like try/catch wouldn't be there.

This is happening with POSTMAN, but not with the Angular application.

Is there a way to identify this error and display a message to the user?

UPDATE: The code is too long to post, but this is what is not working:

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/newlead', async (payload, res, next) => {
    try{
    let test=JSON.parse(payload.body)
    console.log("ok")
    }
    catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
    return;
    }
    res.json(payload.body)

});
module.exports = router;
```

This is my middleware at index.js

```
//Middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, content-type");
    next();
})
app.use(express.json()); //to read bodies
```

Comment: Are you aware that is not valid JSON? https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Its not, that is what Im saying... my question is why try/parse is not detecting the JSON.parse error, and Im getting an error on the terminal when sending that specific JSON.

Comment: Show us where the `try/catch` is and where the `JSON.parse()` is in your code.  And, if the `router.post()` is Express, where is the `payload` argument coming from as that's not how Express works.  We need to see ALL the relevant code.

Comment: If this is Express, you need some middleware to actually read the body of the request to populate `req.body` with the parsed result and then the error would be inside that middleware.  Again, we need to see ALL the relevant code here, not just some of it.

Comment: Im updating the answer now :)

Comment: I can read "payload" just fine, and Im even saving on the database the content of the JSON. The problem is when the JSON contains errors.

Comment: Your handler isn't called at all correct?  (put a console.log right at the beginning of it to confirm.)  The express.json() middleware will encounter an error parsing any body marked with a mime type of `application/json` that is not valid JSON, (due to the characters `"\D..."`) and will return (by default) an HTML response with an error that says something like "Syntax Error: Unexpected token D in JSON at position X..." If you want to handle that error, you can do so by [installing an error handler that handles the json middleware error](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `express.json()` middleware is encountering an error when parsing the invalid JSON sent by the client, and the framework is serving up a default error handling response.

To handle the error in a custom way, consider installing custom error handling middleware like this:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.type === 'entity.parse.failed') {
    // Your custom error handler here
    res.status(500).send('The client sent invalid JSON');
  } else {
    // Something else went wrong. Pass it along.
    next(err);
  }
})
```

Important:  ensure this middleware is installed last, after all other `app.use` directives.

Comment: Worked as a charm. Im happy I've leant something new. Thanks so much Wyck.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware because express can't parse the *not valid json*.  Thats why your try catch doesn't works

```
// ...
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Handle a parse error
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send('error parsing data')
    } else {
        next()
    }
})
```

Comment: They're already using express.json().  The problem is that they haven't installed an error handler to catch the error coming from the middleware.  So your answer is 1/2 correct  (they need to add the "handle a parse error" error handler).  And your answer doesn't really describe the problem that was encountered.  express.json middleware did, indeed attempt to parse the json, and encountered the parse error, and passed it along, but with no user-installed error handling middleware installed, you just get the default error handler response, which serves the HTML error mentioned in the question.

Comment: body-parser.json isn't needed if express.json is being used.  But an error-handler is needed.